# Dynamic data not showing up when I serialize the data

Tags: jquery, html

I am using the following code to to dynamically add another input text box.  The problem I have is the data from the added input text boxes are not showing when I serialize the data and pass it to my php script.

Any ideas what I m doing wrong??

Thanks

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="control-group" id="ports">
<label class="control-label" for="dataport1">dataport</label>
<div class="controls">
    <input type="text" id="dataport_1" name="dataport_1" placeholder="Type something">
</div> <!-- end controls -->
</div><!-- end control-group-->
<div class>
    <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="addportbtn">Add Another Port</a>
</div>
```

**JQUERY SCRIPT**

```
function addPorts()
{

    var count = 2;
    var numports = 2;
    var idnum;

    $('#addportbtn').click(function() {
    //alert(count);
    numports = idnum;
    var addHtml =   '<div class="control-group">' +
            '<label class="control-label" for="dataports">data port</label>'+
            '<div class="controls">'+
            '<input type="text" id="dataport_idnum" placeholder="Type something">'+
            '</div> <!-- end controls -->'+
            '</div><!-- end cotrol-group-->'
        $( "#ports:last" ).after(addHtml);

        numports = numports + 1;
        count++;

    }); //end click
}
```

Comment: Your variables are local to the function, not the window, and thus they will not be correctly updated when the function is called.

Comment: I am new at this so any help you an give will much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues with this code.  I will start with the html:

```
<div class="control-group" id="ports">
<label class="control-label" for="dataport1">dataport</label>
<!--                                      ^ no underscore, which means this won't work correctly -->
<div class="controls">
    <input type="text" id="dataport_1" name="dataport_1" placeholder="Type something">
</div> <!-- end controls -->
</div><!-- end control-group-->
<div class>
<!-- ^ the class attribute without a value.  While it may not cause parsing issues, its good to fix this anyway if you aren't going to use it -->
    <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="addportbtn">Add Another Port</a>
</div>
```

And now the javascript:

```
function addPorts()
{

    var count = 2;    //  Every single one of these variables is local to the function
    var numports = 2; //  And thus cannot be accessed, and are re-initialized
    var idnum;        //  every time the function is called
    //   ^ this variable is not incremented, so it will always be undefined
    $('#addportbtn').click(function() { // and on that note, every time addPorts()
    //alert(count);                     // called, it attaches another click
    numports = idnum;                   // handler
    var addHtml =   '<div class="control-group">' +
            '<label class="control-label" for="dataports">data port</label>'+ //this label won't attach to the input, as there is no input with the id of 'dataports'
            '<div class="controls">'+
            '<input type="text" id="dataport_idnum" placeholder="Type something">'+ //idnum is not parsed, strings are not parsed into variables.  You must escape them first.
            '</div> <!-- end controls -->'+
            '</div><!-- end cotrol-group-->'
        $( "#ports:last" ).after(addHtml);

        numports = numports + 1; //again, variables are local to function, so doing this doesn't do anything
        count++;                 // is pointless, isn't used.

    }); //end click
}
```

And now, the fixes...

The serialize method, as linked below, is usually applied to forms, not divs.

```
<form id="ports">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="dataport_1">data port</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="dataport_1" name="dataport_1" placeholder="Type something" />
        </div>
        <!-- end controls -->
    </div>
    <!-- end control-group-->
    <div> <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="addportbtn">Add Another Port</a>

    </div>
</form>
```

jQuery's [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) method operates off of the element's name attribute, so for it to work, it must be specified:

```
var numports = 2; // make variable global, so it can be accessed by any function
$(function () { //execute on dom ready, so events are bound correctly.
    $('#addportbtn').click(function () {
        var addHtml = '<div class="control-group">' +
            '<label class="control-label" for="dataport_' + numports + '">data port</label>' +
            '<div class="controls">' +
            '<input type="text" id="dataport_' + numports + '" name="dataport_' + numports + '" placeholder="Type something"/>' +
                                                       //        ^ name specified
            '</div> <!-- end controls -->' +
            '</div><!-- end cotrol-group-->'
        $("#ports .control-group:last").after(addHtml);
        numports++;
    });
});
```

Now, when the form is serialized, it will correctly add the relevant input fields.

Here is a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Daedalus/SFjfB/3/).

Comment: Note that global variables, in my opinion, should be used sparingly.  There are other methods of keeping track of such data, such as the [`.data()`](http://jsfiddle.net/Daedalus/SFjfB/3/) method of jQuery, since you are using that.